# Training for shoveling snow

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique, home-exercise

I'm a pretty active 45 year old weight lifter. Here in the mid atlantic our winters are annoying. And,  when it snows, I have a lot of the white stuff to move via snow blower and shovel. What I am finding is a lot of  upper arm discomfort after a day out in the cold  muck. I get a shooting pain from my shoulder to mid arm along the bone between the bicep and tricep.

I'm thinking that I need to modify my training so that I can accommodate the strain of snow removal better. But what exercises would be best? Sure,  I'm getting older and don't recover  like I used to... But that is just another  thing to deal with. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you thought about the position your body is in when shoveling? If you are pretty active and reasonably strong it may be more of an issue of repetition in a poor position. Are your shoulders rolled back in a safe and strong position? Are you using the shovel as a lever with your forward hand as a fulcrum and your back hand pushing down? Are you lifting with your legs or is it all arms?

Comment: I suppose bad form is always a possibility, or maybe the probability. When I was younger, plowing through wasn't a big deal. But now... I do use one of those ergonomic shovels, so I'm not bending over much. But, yes... I think I was using my front hand as a fulcrum. AND, the snow was very wet and heavy. So, bad technique needs to be corrected. Yes. But I still think I need to up my training. No?

Comment: I would not initially think it is a muscle strength or endurance issue due to your description of the pain. Soreness would indicate a need for training but true pain indicates, typically, a different analysis. Perhaps there are trained PTs participating here who could guide you further.

Comment: Is it one arm only? Do you switch arms every few minutes when shoveling (I do). I'm older than you but my workouts are mostly dance & yoga.

Comment: I probably don't switch enough. While I do get pain in both arms. My left is most severe. Which makes sense since I am right handed... I think it makes sense,  any way.

Comment: I tend to use my legs for an extra "umf" when tossing snow in Michigan, but then again I've never felt great after shoveling. Squat, shovel some snow, then thrust up using legs and arms to propel the snow. Uses less back. Just an idea. This could potentially be bad form

Comment: More under the area of technique, I've had a lot of luck with a fluid squat, scoop, and fling. Most of the effort is in the legs. The arms serve to hold onto the shovel toward the blade and pushing from the handle. That said, it's something which I suspect requires good knees because I've seen others attempt it and complain of knee pain pretty soon in.

Answer (score 3):

Dumbbell Rows and Deadlifts have helped me while shoveling. Also a strong core is going to be huge in the overall movement.

Try Cable Choppers for core development, single arm rows, or conventional deadlifts.

You could also push a sled with 45 lb plates on it. I forget what they are called, but that should give you that positional form similar to shoveling and the calf/quad strength to PUSH THAT SNOW

-Midwest Winter Bearer :)